# functional testing with selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I wanted to invite friends by email in a facebook group using selenium

I used the following code bt it wont work

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')


url = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/356133891124303/"
driver.get(url)

invite_frnd = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='groupsNewMembersLink']/div/div/a[3]")
input_email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id= 'groupMembersInput']")



actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.click(invite_friends)
actions.move_to_element(input_email)
actions.send_keys("a@a.com")
actions.keyDown(Keys.SHIFT)
actions.keyDown(Keys.RETURN)
action.keyUp(Keys.RETURN)
actions.perform()

driver.close()
```

what I'm doing wrong? please suggest the right way.

Comment: You probably don't need to use the `ActionChains()` class for this sequence. `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='groupsNewMembersLink']/div/div/a[3]").click() driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id= 'groupMembersInput']").send_keys("a@a.com")` and then `.click()` on whatever is the element to send the request.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use straighforward approach like:

```
invite_frnd = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#groupsNewMembersLink>div>div>a:nth-child(3)")); 

input_email = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#groupMembersInput));
input_email.sendKeys("abracadra@a.com");

invite_frnd.click();
```

example of Robot class instance and how can you use it:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
//        setClipboardData("C:\\test.png");
        robot.delay(2000);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

imho , straighforward approach described above will be better for your task.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","your path");    
driver = new ChromeDriver();

invite_frnd = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='groupsNewMembersLink']/div/div/a[3]""))
invite_frnd.click();

input_email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id= 'groupMembersInput']"));
input_email.sendKeys("abracadra@a.com");
```

and you can add chrome capabilities to maximize window

```
DesiredCapabilities chromeCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
chromeCapabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--start-maximized"));
```